# Help needed in understanding how a certain result was found.

Tags: calculus, summation, harmonic-analysis

$$\sum_{j=1}^{a-1}\widetilde{\zeta}(j+1)\widetilde{\zeta}(2a-j)=\sum_{j=1}^{a-1}\widetilde{\zeta}(2j)\widetilde{\zeta}(2a+1-2j)$$

I'm trying to understand how the two are equal. At first, I thought they separated the sum according to the parity of $j$ but I soon discarded that thought. This step is crucial as the paper is on an identity I need to evaluate a certain integral. Any help however small will be appreciated.

Comment: More generally $\sum_{j=A}^Bf(j)=\sum_{j=A}^Bf(A+B-j)$. Unfortunately, this example doesn't quite seem to work.

Comment: @J.G. I think I've seen that identity before. Isn't it the one of reversing the order in which the terms are added? From the last to the first term? If it is, then I've already tried it. You're right though. It doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: What is $\tilde{\zeta}$? Is it related to the Riemann zeta function?

Comment: @Sangchul Lee From what I can tell, it represents the Dirichlet Eta function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for any sequence $f(n)$ and for any $a \geq 1$, we have

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{a-1} f(j+1)f(2a-j) = \sum_{j=1}^{a-1} f(2j)f(2a+1-2j). \tag{1} $$

Indeed, write $g(j) = f(j)f(2a+1-j)$ and note that $g(j) = g(2a+1-j)$. Then substituting $j' = 2a-j-1$,

\begin{align*}
2\cdot\text{[LHS of (1)]}
&= \sum_{j=1}^{a-1} g(j+1) + \sum_{j'=a}^{2a-2} g(2a-j') \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{a-1} g(j+1) + \sum_{j'=a}^{2a-2} g(j'+1) \\
&= g(2) + g(3) + \cdots + g(2a-2) + g(2a-1)
\end{align*}

On the other hand, substituting $j' = a - j$,

\begin{align*}
2\cdot\text{[RHS of (1)]}
&= \sum_{j=1}^{a-1} g(2j) + \sum_{j'=1}^{a-1} g(2a - 2j') \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{a-1} [g(2j) + g(2j+1)] \\
&= g(2) + g(3) + \cdots + g(2a-2) + g(2a-1)
\end{align*}

Therefore $\text{(1)}$ holds.

---

**Visual Proof.** For each set $I \subseteq \{1,2,3, \ldots, 2a\}$ of indices, I will visualize the sum $\sum_{i \in I} g(i)$ by a row of $2a$ circles, in which the $i$-th circle is filled if $i \in I$ (so that $g(i)$ is present in the sum) and empty if $i \notin I$ (so that $g(i)$ is absent from the sum).

> **Example.** If $a = 4$ and $I = \{2, 3, 6\}$, then
> $$\sum_{i \in \{2,3,6\}} g(i) = \text{○●●○○●○○}. $$
> Since $g(i) = g(9-i)$, it is also true that
> $$\sum_{i \in \{2,3,6\}} g(i) = \sum_{i \in \{3,6,7\}} g(i) = \text{○○●○○●●○}. $$
> Note that $\text{○○●○○●●○}$ is the reverse of $\text{○●●○○●○○}$.

In general, if $s$ is the string of ○'s and ●'s representing a sum, then the reverse of $s$ also represents the same sum. Keeping this in mind, we find that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{a-1} g(i+1)
&= \text{○}\underbrace{\color{blue}{\text{●●}\cdots\text{●●}}}_{2\text{ to } a}\text{○○}\cdots\text{○○} \\
&= \text{○○}\cdots\text{○○}\underbrace{\color{red}{\text{●●}\cdots\text{●●}}}_{a+1\text{ to } 2a-1}\text{○} \tag{reversal} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}[\text{○}\color{blue}{\text{●●}\cdots\text{●●}}\color{red}{\text{●●}\cdots\text{●●}}\text{○}] \tag{averaging} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=2}^{2a-1} g(i)
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{a-1} g(2j)
&= \text{○}\color{blue}{\text{●}\text{○}\text{●}\cdots\text{○}\text{●}\text{○}}\text{○} \\
&= \text{○}\color{red}{\text{○}\text{●}\text{○}\text{●}\cdots\text{○}\text{●}}\text{○} \tag{reversal} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2}[ \text{○}\color{blue}{\text{●}}\color{red}{\text{●}}\color{blue}{\text{●}}\color{red}{\text{●}} \cdots \color{blue}{\text{●}}\color{red}{\text{●}}\text{○} ] \tag{averaging} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=2}^{2a-1} g(i)
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice solution. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around the second sums, namely, $$\sum_{j'=a}^{2a-2}g(2a-j')$$ and $$\sum_{j'=1}^{a-1} g(2a-2j')$$. Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I can't see what yet. I'll continue looking at it though. Perhaps it will click soon. Utmost gratitude @Sangchul Lee.

Comment: @KaraboDibakoane I included a visual explanation as to what I did in my proof.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now. Please correct me if I'm wrong here. So basically, $$\sum_{j=1}^{a-1}g(j+1)+\sum_{j'=a}^{2a-2}g(2a-j')$$ is the sum of the series $$g(2)+g(3)+\cdots+g(a-1)+g(a)$$ and its reverse $$g(a)+g(a-1)+\cdots+g(3)+g(2)$$ or am I wrong? But this has $2a$ terms and is just the same as $$2\sum_{j=1}^{a-1} g(j+1)$$, isn't it? Which, from the result you obtained, is the same as $$\sum_{j=2}^{2a-1} g(j)$$. Wow! What an ingenious approach. Thank you so much once again. You saved my life. Now I can proceed with the derivation.

Comment: My apologies. I meant $2a-2$ terms. ;-)